# Definition of topology in Galois group

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

In the book Algebraic numbers and algebraic functions of E. Artin, chapter six, page 103-104.

[image]

Artin never says that   $\Omega$ is of characteristic $0$ or $p>0$.

1) But by defining of neighboorhoods by finite fields, $\Omega$ is assumed of characteristic $p>0$?

2) In this case, is $F$ is necessarily finite?

Thank you all.

Comment: "Finite" should be read as "finite-dimensional" (over $F$).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan; Thank you.